# Definite integral and remainder using three terms of a power series

Tags: calculus, power-series

Problem: Approximate

\begin{equation}
\int_0^{0.5}\dfrac{x}{1+x^5}\,dx
\end{equation}

using three terms of the series expansion and approximate the remainder.

Work:

\begin{eqnarray}
\dfrac{x}{1+x^5}&\approx\sum_{n=0}^2(-1)^nx^{5n-1}\\
\int_0^{0.5}\sum_{n=0}^2(-1)^nx^{5n-1}\,dx&=\left[\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^2\dfrac{(-1)^nx^{5n+2}}{5n+2}\right]_0^{0.5}\\
&=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^2\dfrac{(-1)^n\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{5n+2}}{5n+2}\\
&=\dfrac{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2}{2}-\dfrac{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^7}{7}+\dfrac{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{12}}{12}\\
&=\frac{1}{8}-\frac{1}{896}+\frac{1}{49152}\\
&=0.124
\end{eqnarray}

How do I estimate the remainder?

I am pretty confident I did the integral correctly and calculated the first 3 terms but I am not sure how to find the remainder? Do I use the integral test?

Comment: It's an alternating series tending toward $0$. So the sum of the remaining terms does not exceed the absolute value of the next term in succession--in this case, the fourth term.

Comment: After estimating the remainder you may find you are entitled to write your answer to a few more decimal places of precision.

Comment: I suppose that you have typo's : $5n-1$ should be $5n+1$